# myswiper.slideTo() is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, swiper.js

i have this error in console, but i dont understand why

```
var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView:1,
    calculateHeight: true,
    spaceBetween: 50,
    watchActiveIndex: true,
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next'
});

  $('input[type=radio][name=radio]').change(function() {
    var indx = $(this).val();
    mySwiper.slideTo(indx,400,false);
});
```

[screen shot of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhCe0.png)

Comment: What is your html ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

mySwiper is not defined in your change function.

I guess if you check the value of mySwiper in your change function, it will be null as it hasn't been set in the contect of your function.

Comment: i try console.log(mySwiper) and it have something

Comment: can you make some code please? I still don't understand how to fix it

Answer (score 9):

Probably you have more then one swiper element - then use array to call slideTo:

```
mySwiper[0].slideTo(1);
```

Comment: Do you know why does this happen? I mean, why does the variable contains an array with two items?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make "mySwiper" golabl so you can call it in other functions
to declare a global variable you must remove "var" and just start typing the variable's name
like this:

```
mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-container', {
    speed: 400,
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView:1,
    calculateHeight: true,
    spaceBetween: 50,
    watchActiveIndex: true,
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next'
});
```

Then you can call it where ever you need

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
mySwiper[mySwiper.length - 1].slideTo(0, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems correct.

Your problem is certainly link to the load of the script.

Check that you correctly load `JQuery`

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

**AND**

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Swiper/3.4.0/js/swiper.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: i download jquery file and include it from folder, 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/my.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swiper.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>

Comment: @SergeySmekodub you need only jquery or vanilla js Swiper lib, not both. And correct your scripts order: 1. jquery, 2. Swiper, 3. my.js (initialization of libs must be in the end because you must load libs before initialization)

Answer (score 0):

You should change the `className` of swiper like this:

```
mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-box', {
    speed: 400,
    loop: true,
    slidesPerView:1,
    calculateHeight: true,
    spaceBetween: 50,
    watchActiveIndex: true,
    prevButton: '.swiper-button-prev',
    nextButton: '.swiper-button-next'
});
```

Comment: Use coding block to style your code as per SO policy